# How to read file formatted in uneven manner?

Tags: python, regex

I have file formatted like this

```
9 0.0351562 0.0713449 -11.4664 -25.9366 -27.955 4 2.38188
10 0.0390625 0.0507383 -12.9466 -30.2437 -29.1045 4 0.616179
11 0.0429688 0.0629145 -12.0125 -37.1503 -32.2795 4 0.569045
12 0.046875 0.046937 -13.2848 -31.9606 -32.5367 4 0.128286
13 0.0507812 0.0541174 -12.6666 -30.7398 -27.4705 4 1.38345
```

Regarding the Python code my idea was to use regex.

```
for line in s.splitlines():
    lst = [i.strip() for j in re.findall(regex, line) for i in j if j]
    print(lst)
```

But how should the regex look like?

The C code line that wrote the file:

```c
fprintf(inf, "%d %g %g %g %g %g %g %g\n", i,frq1,
        spec[i],dbspec, naive_spec[i], dtemp[i],
        dof[i], Fvalues[i]);
```

I have 8 variables in line, 1 integer and 7 doubles in Python syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
with open('path/to/file') as infile:
    for line in infie:
        nums = [float(i) for i in line.split()]
        # do stuff with nums
```

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use a regex for this since the values are all whitespace delimited. Here's how to do using the `split()` string method:

```
kinds = [int] + [float]*7  # types expected
with open('uneven.txt') as file:
    for line in file:
        row = map(lambda v: v[0](v[1]), zip(kinds, line.split()))
        print(row)
```